# Ubuntu 14.04 wirelss card all seems installed but cannot scan for networks

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I seem to have an issue on my new Ubuntu 14.0.4.3 installation on my HP Presario CQ60 with a Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express).

I cannot scan for or view any wireless networks, despite the wifi being enabled and the following below seeming to indicate (to my beginner self) that the wireless card is enabled, not blocked and has a driver installed:

rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:23:4e:00:f5:13
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.19.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:23 memory:c2000000-c200ffff
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

lspci -nn|grep -e 0200 -e 0280

```
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet [10de:0760] (rev a2)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:137b]
Kernel driver in use: ath5k
```

I have searched for hours to no avail. I've also noted that when I use a modprobe command to uninstall and reinstall a component, my wireless card acquires a hard block, which only resetting the BIOS to default can reverse.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: You can try to reinstall the driver. It might help.

Comment: You can always try disabling hardware cryptography. `sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt=1`.  If it works I'll provide an answer with a way to make it permanent.

Comment: Hi @Stunts, I think this might have already been done? It seems to be disabled in /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf. I tried the command and nothing happened before or after a reboot.

Comment: Well, then can you try to boot a Live CD/USB with Ubuntu 15.10 and see if it works on a more recent kernel?

Comment: When I load a 15.10 live CD, it says it's dabbled by a hardware switch. The annoying thing is it has connected to my network once since I installed Ubuntu, so I know it's capable of it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't appear to have an IP address.  Try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.100 up` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @quintablet, nothing changed unfortunately

Comment: Do you have an IP address?  In your command 'iwconfig' above, the print out says that your access point is 'Not-Associated'.  What does 'sudo ifconfig' give you.  It should list your devices (eth0, wlan0..) and show what IP address is associated with that device.

Comment: He is not connected to a network, how can he assign himself an IP address?

Comment: Hi @quintablet, I've edited the question to give you the output

Comment: Look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160177).  Perhaps your card is encrypted.  You can edit the file: "/etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf" and add the line: "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" to it.   Then execute the two commands: "sudo modprobe -rfv ath5k", then "sudo modprobe -v ath5k" to reload the config file and remove the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183347) will help. And read [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/238420) for more detailed caused.

Sorry can't make it as comment, didn't have previledge yet.

Comment: Unfortunately not. There was an entry in blacklist-ath_pci.conf, but uncommenting and restarting didn't do anything.